# Realm migration introducing primary key

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-migration

Currently, my Realm database contains a plain array of `MyData` objects:

```
class MyData: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var age = 0
}
```

For instance, it may contain

```
[
    ["Alice", 12],
    ["Bob", 13],
    ["Alice", 22],
    ["Carolina", 13],
    ["Bob", 20]
]
```

I am going to rework it so that to make `name` unique keeping the biggest `age`:

```
[
    ["Alice", 22],
    ["Bob", 20],
    ["Carolina", 13]
]
```

also, I want to make `name` a primary key to avoid duplication in future.

So I changed class description as

```
class MyData: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var age = 0
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "name"
    }
}
```

And now I need to provide a migration block:

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(
    schemaVersion: 1,
    migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
        switch oldSchemaVersion {
        case 0:
           migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: MyData.className()) { (oldObject, newObject) in
            // how to do it?
        }
        default:
            break
    }
})
```

I do not understand what to do in enumeration block. In my example, I have five "old" objects (without primary key), and I will have three "new" objects (with primary key), so how do I do this transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you just try to increment schema version and add property `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded` to true ?

```
Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
    schemaVersion: 2,
    migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in },
    deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true
)
```

EDIT:

Sorry, it's not true because you need to keep only oldest people so try use `delete` method of realm migration object:

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(
schemaVersion: 1,
migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
    switch oldSchemaVersion {
    case 0:
       var objects: [String: Any] = []
       migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: MyData.className()) { 
       (oldObject, newObject) in
           if let age = oldObject["age"] as? Int, age > objects[oldObject["name"]] {
               migration.delete(oldObject["name"])
               objects[oldObject["name"]] = oldObject
           } else {
               migration.delete(oldObject)
           }

       }
    default:
        break
    }
})
```

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Migration.html#/s:FC10RealmSwift9Migration6deleteFCS_13DynamicObjectT_

Comment: `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded` is not an option in my case, because it would lead to user re-login and other bad user experience

Comment: Yes sorry, I edit my answer. Try to use `migration.delete` and delete only targeted objects.

Answer (score 0):

```swift
func realmConfiguration(schemaVersion: UInt64) {
       let config = Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: schemaVersion,
                                        migrationBlock: { _, oldSchemaVersion in
                                            if oldSchemaVersion < schemaVersion {}
       })
       Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
   }
```

call this function in appDelegate

```swift
//Bump the schemaVersion when ever you need migration
realmConfiguration(schemaVersion: 2)
```

Comment: I understand general pattern of migration. My question is about the specific case when I want to migrate from array of structures without primary key to array of unique (in terms of primary key) structures.